# Adverse affects of killing DW20.exe on a Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a Windows Server 2003 virtual instance that I recently noticed DW20.exe was running constantly and entirely utilizing one whole core.  I can't deduce what it's doing, except that it's PID is so low it starts right after boot.

I'd like to kill this but do not know what the adverse consequences might be.  What problems might I face for terminating this CPU thief?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841477/en

Comment: That's the odd thing...I knew it was an Office error reporting agent but I not running any Office products that I'm aware of.

Comment: Usually when dw20 is running with high CPU you've had alot of unreported app faults - since it's win 2k3 you might as well disable it since nothing it reports will ever get fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DW20.exe it's [Windows Error Reporting tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841477/en-us) (absolutely useless software IMO) so you can disable it as described in this KB article